# Add Wordpress Pages to their own RSS feed and not main RSS feed using Plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins, rss

I'm learning to write Wordpress plugins and found some code that adds Wordpress pages to the RSS feed.

I used the following code in my Wordpress Plugin and it works great!
https://www.thewebtaylor.com/articles/wordpress-add-pages-rss-feed

I'm trying to figure out how to send Wordpress Pages to their own separate feed and not include it in the Wordpress default RSS.

Answer (score 0):

`I found a solution for this.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 't5_pages_in_feed' );

/**
 * Set post type to 'page' if it was requested.
 *
 * @param  object $query
 * @return void
 */
function t5_pages_in_feed( &$query )
{
    if ( isset ( $_GET['post_type'] ) && $_GET['post_type'] === 'page' && is_feed() )
    {
        $query->set( 'post_type', 'page' );
    }
}`
```

Now you get the page feed at /feed/?post_type=page.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52853/how-to-get-a-feed-for-post-type-page